# C#: How to change data field type in Realm database?

Tags: c#, realm

I have created a Realm database with a wrong data field type, and I want to change it (from int to string). It doesn't seem like it's possible to do it in Realm Studio - I was able to delete things, but not to change any data field types. I have looked at this [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L131), but I couldn't figure out how to translate it to C#.

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#migrations but it's different in Java

Comment: Have tried to change the SchemaVersion, but in the terminal output, I get the following error: `Bad changeset received: Schema mismatch: Property 'Height' in class 'PlayerModel' is of type Integer on one side and type String on the other`

Comment: Hold on, are you using Realm Sync? Like, Realm Object Server and stuff?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using

Comment: Realm Sync operates in **ADDITIVE SCHEMA MODE**, so that means you cannot change field data types, only way to change it is to add a new field, and map the existing values over. Also, if you want to change a primary key data type... I don't think you can without creating a new class for it. If you're not in production yet, then just clear and recreate everything